# wrong output when transfering datagrid to word/excel/pdf

Tags: asp.net, excel, pdf, datagridview, ms-word

hye, i have made this code which i have tried separately from my current web and it work perfectly but when i combine it with my web, i didn't get the output that was generated in the gridview. here is the code that i had used.

```
protected void Wordbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (maxdata.Checked == true)
    {
        wordmax();
    }
    if (curdata.Checked == true)
    {
        wordcur();
    }        
}
protected void excelbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (maxdata.Checked == true)
    {
        excelmax();
    }
    if (curdata.Checked == true)
    {
        excelcur();
    }
}
protected void pdfbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (maxdata.Checked == true)
    {
        pdfmax();
    }
    if (curdata.Checked == true)
    {
        pdfcur();
    }
}
public void wordmax()
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MaxdataExport.doc");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word ";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    gridmaxdata.AllowPaging = false;
    gridmaxdata.DataBind();
    gridmaxdata.RenderControl(hw);

    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
public void wordcur()
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=CurrentDataExport.doc");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word ";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    gridcurdata.AllowPaging = false;
    gridcurdata.DataBind();
    gridcurdata.RenderControl(hw);

    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
public void excelmax()
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
     "attachment;filename=MaxDataExport.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    gridmaxdata.AllowPaging = false;
    gridmaxdata.DataBind();

    //Change the Header Row back to white color
    gridmaxdata.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");


    gridmaxdata.RenderControl(hw);

    //style to format numbers to string
    string style = @"&lt;style&gt; .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } &lt;/style&gt;";
    Response.Write(style);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
public void excelcur()
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
     "attachment;filename=CurrentdataExport.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    gridcurdata.AllowPaging = false;
    gridcurdata.DataBind();

    //Change the Header Row back to white color
    gridcurdata.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");


    gridcurdata.RenderControl(hw);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //style to format numbers to string
    string style = @"&lt;style&gt; .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } &lt;/style&gt;";
    Response.Write(style);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
public void pdfmax()
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MaxDataExport.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gridmaxdata.AllowPaging = false;
    gridmaxdata.DataBind();
    gridmaxdata.RenderControl(hw);

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
public void pdfcur()
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=CurrentdataExport.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    gridcurdata.AllowPaging = false;
    gridcurdata.DataBind();
    gridcurdata.RenderControl(hw);

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

this is the code that i used to create the datagridview

```
public void maxdatatable()
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\webradiation\\App_Data\\Radiation.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

    //Bind SQLDataSource to GridView for max data
    // Create SQLDataSource.
    SqlDataSource sqlDataSource1 = new SqlDataSource();
    sqlDataSource1.ID = "SqlDataSource123";
    this.Page.Controls.Add(sqlDataSource1);

    // Bind ConnectionString to SQLDataSource.
    sqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    // Retrieve records
    sqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT top 30 [date], [data] FROM [loc1] WHERE (([data] >= '2') AND (([date] >= '" + combdatetime11.ToString() + "') AND ([date] <= '" + combdatetime21.ToString() + "'))) ORDER BY [data] DESC, [date] DESC";

    gridmaxdata.DataSource = sqlDataSource1;
    gridmaxdata.DataBind();
}

public void currdata()
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\webradiation\\App_Data\\Radiation.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    // Create SQLDataSource.
    SqlDataSource sqlDataSource2 = new SqlDataSource();
    sqlDataSource2.ID = "SqlDataSource12";
    this.Page.Controls.Add(sqlDataSource2);

    // Bind ConnectionString to SQLDataSource.
    sqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    // Retrieve records 
    sqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT [date], [data] FROM [loc1] WHERE (([date] >= '" + combdatetime11.ToString() + "') AND ([date] < '" + combdatetime21.ToString() + "'))";

    gridcurdata.DataSource = sqlDataSource2;
    gridcurdata.DataBind();
}
```

for the word document, the output that i got is

```
(div) (/div)
```

*i have to used "(" and ")" to replace "<" and ">" because this pageweb make it disappear

the excel is like this

```
(style) .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } (/style)(div)(div)
```

the pdf file i got an error saying that the document does not have pages.

do you not where did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a extension function to convert the datasource datatable to excel and then send it to client using `Response.WriteFile` method

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void ToExcel(this DataTable source, string destinationXlsxPath)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data");
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(source, true);
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(destinationXlsxPath);
            pck.SaveAs(file);
        }
    }

}
```

EPPlus: http://epplus.codeplex.com/